# ¿Por que me sale el error ActionController::UrlGenerationError en Ruby al intentar crear un nuevo registro?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Tengo una vista donde voy crear series y tengo un listado, de el listado me vinculo a la agregación de Mis series, pero marca este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

archivo index.html.erb

```
<section class="capturar">


</section>

<section class="detalles">

</section>


<center>
<h2 style="color:blue;font-size:32px"> Lista de Series </h2>
<%= link_to "Agregar nueva Serie", new_series_path,:class=>"nuevo" %>


</center>
```

Archivo _formulario_guardar_Guardar.html.erb

```
<section class="formulario">

<%= form_for @serie do |f| %> 


<form>


 <%= f.label "Titulo" %>
      <%= f.text_field :class=>"caja"%>



   <p>
      <%= f.submit "Enviar",:class=>"button success" %> <%= link_to "Cancelar", series_path,:class=>"button alert" %>
   </p>

   </form>

<% end %>
</section>

<br><br>
```

Metodo new

```
  def new
           @serie = Serie.new();

  end
```

Se supone que lo que debía hacer el método es mostrarme al menos la pantalla para poder crear una nueva serie

Tengo otro metodo y clase de la misma forma que esta solo que no se si las rutas estan mal o modificadas o por alguna razon me esta trayendo el metodo de actualizar porque al parecer pide parametros cuestion que no deberia de ser asi.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que no está el código que corresponde al error, mi respuesta está basada en simple suposición.
Tal como dice el mensaje de error, tu problema está en el archivo `app/views/series/_formulario_guardar_serie.html.erb` en la línea `#3`. Ahí "asumo" debes tener un `serie_path` al cual no le estás pasando ningún id o un valor nulo (en el caso que estés haciendo algo como `serie_path(serie)` y no hayas asignado un valor para `serie`). Espero esto te guíe a lo que provoca tu error, sino agrega más del código relevante para ver que pueda ser.

Como consejo para futuras preguntas:

- No pongas *Aqui esta mi codigo de el Listado*, sino el nombre del archivo que estás mostrando
- En vez de poner un pantallazo de tu error, mejor copia el texto del error, que es mucho mas fácil de manipular para quienes te podríamos responder, además que la imagen que pusiste hay que verla con lupa para ver el detalle. El texto lo puedes copiar del log que va mostrando en la consola del servidor o, en el peor caso, de la misma página donde te muestra el error.

Comment: ya había agregado el archivo solo que no le puse el titulo que debería, como sea gracias por tu respuesta.